# Какие действия выполняет код?

Tags: c++builder, c++

В общем есть такой код, просьба пояснить какие действия выполняет. В частности желательно объяснить действие `friend complex operator (+,-,/,*)(complex, complex);` и там где отмечены "+"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio>
using namespace std;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class complex
{
        double a;
        double b;
        public:
                complex(): a(0), b(0){};
                complex (double aa) : a(aa), b(0){};
                complex (double aa, double bb) : a(aa), b(bb){};
        void show();
        complex operator +(complex c)
                {return complex (a + c.a, b+ c.b);}
        friend complex operator -(complex, complex);
        friend complex operator *(complex, complex);
        friend complex operator /(complex, complex);
        friend int operator !=(complex, complex);
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, complex);
};
        void complex::show()
                {cout << a << '+' << b << 'i';}

        complex operator -(complex c1, complex c2) //+
                {return complex(c1.a - c2.a, c1.b - c2.b);}

        int operator !=(complex c1, complex c2) //+
                {return ((c1.a != c2.a) && (c1.b != c2.b));}

        ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const complex c1) //+
                {
                        if ( c1.b < 0)
                        return(out << c1.a << c1.b << 'i');
                        else
                        return(out << c1.a << '+' << c1.b << 'i');
                }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
/*int main()
{
        int A,B,C,D,F,G;
        cout << "Enter A : ";
        cin >> A;
        cout << "Enter B : ";
        cin >> B;
        complex x(A,B);
        cout << "Complex y : " << x << endl;
        cout << "Enter C : ";
        cin >> C;
        cout << "Enter D : ";
        cin >> D;
        complex y(C,D);
        cout << "Complex y : " << y << endl;
        getch();
        return 0;
}*/
```

Answer (score 1):

**friend complex operator** - это бинарный оператор, друг класса. Друг - значит , что он не объявлен в классе, но имеет доступ к закрытым и защищенным полям и методам.
Класс для работы с комплексными числами, читайте википедию о них.Оператор **<<** - записывает комплексное число в поток вывода, которым может быть файл, консоль, и т.п. **show** - печатает число в консоль